# Passing attribute to soap Header

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

i am trying to re-create below soap request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:data="http://test.gbd.chdb.test.net">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <userId>5647775-b7d7-4a45-9570-654116547654</userId>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <data:getPerson>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <iin>700521700054</iin>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <consentConfirmed>true</consentConfirmed>
          </data:getPerson>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

using below php scrip

```
$opts = array(some attributes);

        $soap_client = new \SoapClient(null,
                                array(
                                    'location' => 'https://test.test.net/testServices/PersonDetailsImplService',
                                    'uri' => 'http://test.gbd.chdb.test.net',
                                    'login'    => 'XXXXXXX',
                                    'password' => 'YYYYYYY',
                                    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                                    'soap_version'=> SOAP_1_1,
                                    'style' => SOAP_RPC,
                                    'use' => SOAP_ENCODED,
                                    'trace'          => true,
                                    'exceptions'     => true,
                                    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts)
                                )
                            );
        $auth = new \stdClass();
            $auth->userId = '5647775-b7d7-4a45-9570-654116547654';
        $header = new \SoapHeader('http://test.gbd.chdb.test.net', 'Header', $auth);

        $soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
        $result = $soap_client->getPerson();
```

Every time i am executing this i am getting response "userId field is missing". Not sure what am i doing wrong as i am setting Header attribute in my script below and setting headers to my SoapClient via __setSoapHeaders.

Been working on it for few days now and went through tons of articles online - still no go. Any help will be hightly appriciated.

Comment: could you please share XML sent via your request using `$soap_client->__getLastRequest()`?

Comment: @DenisAlimov, thanks for looking into this. When print_r($soap_client->__getLastRequest()) - i get nothing, no response is returned.

Comment: you must call __getLastRequest after soap call. in your case after line `$result = $soap_client->getPerson();`. still empty request?

Comment: cannot really do that as script stops at point $result = $soap_client->getPerson() with error "userId field is missing"

Comment: as you have `'exceptions'     => true,` in your SoapClient you can make a call inside try-catch block, so in catch you can call `$soap_client->__getLastRequest()`

Comment: try {
            $response = $soap_client->getPerson($params);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print_r($soap_client->__getLastRequest());
        } -- still nothing

Comment: Can you pass a stdClass directly into SoapHeader like that? The Documentation is a bit ambiguous here in my opinion but you may need to use a SoapVar instead? That or try to pass it an array instead of a stdClass.

Comment: I see that you initiate SoapClient in non-WSDL mode. from your previous question I see that you have problems to access wsdl with basic auth from client, actually it's a little complicated. as a workaround I would suggest to save wsdl file locally and initiate SoapClient with local copy of wsdl. and then try to call `$soap_client->__getFunctions()` to check. and after that try to call `getPerson` again, looks like you don't send any request at all, maybe it's because non-WSDL mode

Comment: @DenisAlimov, any idea how i can do it in wsdl mode? I also tried it at some point but was not even able to connect to server. Alway getting error "unable to read .wsdl"

Comment: I already suggested: `as a workaround I would suggest to save wsdl file locally and initiate SoapClient with local copy of wsdl.`

Comment: That one tried as well - getting error "incorectly formated wsdl"